# Linux Bash - how to do the following with (),&& and &

Tags: linux, bash, operators

I want to execute a script but as soons as it started, I want it to echo the PID, so I'm doing the following:

```
./dummy.SCRIPT & echo $!
```

but I also want it to echo something when it is done executing the script so I'm guessing it should look something like:

```
( ./dummy.SCRIPT & echo $! ) && echo "Task Done!"
```

But it doesn't seem to work, the "Task Done!" echo executes at the same time the dummy.SCRIPT start's, what am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Try `( ./dummy.SCRIPT && echo $$ ) && echo "Task Done!"`

Comment: How about `./dummy.SCRIPT & echo $! && fg && echo "Task Done!"`?

Comment: @M.Becerra that didn't seem to work either, i get both the PID and message when the SCRIPT is done runnning.

Comment: @Phylogenesis That did the trick!, thank you very much!

Comment: Update: However i discovered that i can't use bg or fg on scripting so i went for "wait" instead of "fg"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a command line execution, write a small script that does that for you.

```
$ cat monitordummy.sh
#!/bin/bash

./dummyscript &
pidofdummy=$!
while ps -p $pidofdummy > /dev/null
do
  sleep 5 # Modify this according to your run time
  echo -n "...." # This will be printed on the stdout
done
echo "Task Done for dummyscript"
```

Run the script:

```
$ chmod u+x monitordummy.sh
$ ./monitordummy.sh
```

Comment: Since i'm running this over SSH, on multiple computers, i prefer just a simple line. but your answer it's much preciated!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but should do what you're describing:

```
{ ./dummy.SCRIPT & PID=$!; echo $PID; } && { wait $PID ; echo "Task Done!"; }
```

In the first block you run the script, save and print its PID. When that was OK, you run the second block in the background waiting for the child process to finish and print your message. Not that `wait` also propagates return code of the finished process, so you could at this point report done or failed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, i was uncertain on how those braces worked, but i went with: ./dummy.script & echo "pid:"$! && wait && echo "Command was completed"